# ubuntu (Linux Mint 19 Tara) 18.04 iperf or iperf3 is missing

Tags: networking, ubuntu, wireless-networking, linux-mint

I am trying to check my wifi speed, but on OpenWrt with opkg it I can find it, but in Bionic I can't find it, this is the output:

```
root@bitang:~# apt update && apt list | grep iperf
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
All packages are up to date.

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.

root@bitang:~#
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a standard installation of Linux Mint 19 Cinnamon 64-bit, these packages are contained in the standard repositories. Performing the command you issued above on a mostly clean, unmodified LM19 installation yields the following results:

```
root@steve-VirtualBox:/home/steve# apt update && apt list | grep iperf  
Hit:1 http://archive.canonical.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease  
Ign:2 http://packages.linuxmint.com tara InRelease                                
Hit:3 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security InRelease                
Hit:4 http://packages.linuxmint.com tara Release                                 
Hit:5 http://ppa.launchpad.net/ichthyo/zeug/ubuntu bionic InRelease              
Hit:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic InRelease                          
Hit:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-updates InRelease                  
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease               
Hit:10 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-backports InRelease         
Hit:11 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release                
Reading package lists... Done                        
Building dependency tree         
Reading state information... Done  
5 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.  

WARNING: apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.  

iperf/bionic-updates 2.0.10+dfsg1-1ubuntu0.18.04.1 amd64  
iperf3/bionic 3.1.3-1 amd64  
libiperf-dev/bionic 3.1.3-1 amd64  
libiperf0/bionic 3.1.3-1 amd64  
root@steve-VirtualBox:/home/steve#
```

Note the difference here where the update portion is actually parsing and updating from the repositories, either you neglected to copy & paste this output into your question, or you appear to not have any repositories active.

I would suggest opening Update Manager in the GUI, and going to Edit - Software Sources, and on the `Official repositories` tab, at the bottom, click `Restore the default settings` and then close the window and select Refresh.

Software Manager application also shows iperf and iperf3 are in the repository and available for installation.

[image: Screenshot of Software Manager when searching for iperf]